# Ошибка в сортировке массива

Tags: массивы, java

```
public class Zad_two {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[5];
    for (int k = 0; k <= a.length; k++)
        a[k] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    for (int k = 0; k <= a.length; k++)
        if (a[k] < a[k + 1]) {
            int t = a[k];
            a[k] = a[k + 1];
            a[k + 1] = t;
        }
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
        //
        System.out.println(a[k]);
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
> at My.Next.Step.Zad_one.main(Zad_one.java:8)`

Answer (score 2):

Надо писать в начале сортировки

```
for (int k = 0; k < a.length - 1; k++)
```

P.S. Действительно, работать сортировка не будет. Если это попытка написать пузырьковый алгоритм, то надо писать так, например (сортирует в порядке возрастания).

```
int t;
for (int k = a.length - 1; k > 0; k--) {
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
   if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
     t = a[i];
     a[i] = a[i+1];
     a[i+1] = t;
   }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: все таже ошибка

Comment: ну да, действительно, зачем нам последний элемент=)

Comment: Сортировать точно не будет.

Comment: теоретически все отрицательные элементы должны быть в начале массива. переставляет, но не все (я прибавил второй рандом с отрицательными числами).

Comment: ответ создал сам:
  int temp;
  int[] a1 = { 6, 2, -3, 7, -1, 8, 9, 0 };
  for (int j = 0; j < (a1.length * a1.length); j++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < a1.length - 1; i++) {
    if (a1[i] > a1[i + 1]) {
     temp = a1[i];
     a1[i] = a1[i + 1];
     a1[i + 1] = temp;
    }
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)